# Mapbox Layer - How to highlight a polygon upon click

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL to create an interactive map. The map's area is divided in multiple polygons. What I want to achieve is this: when a user clicks on a polygon this polygon is highlighted. I am following this example from Mapbox Docs: [Create a hover effect](https://%20https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/)

My code is the following:

```
map.getSource('json_source').setData(//my_data_source);

var current_layer = '1st_layers_name'; //this is the layer that contains the polygons

var current_label_layer = '2nd_layers_name'+'_labels'; //this is a layer that contains some labels to appear on each polygon's center

if (!map.getLayer(current_layer)) {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': current_layer,
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'json_source',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': {
                property: 'properties_count',
                stops: [[...]]
            },
            'fill-opacity': [
                'case',
                ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'current'], false],
                0.7,
                1
            ]
        }
    });
}

map.addLayer({
    "id": current_label_layer,
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": //data_source_for_this_layer
        } ,
    "layout": {
        "text-field": "{properties_count}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
  "text-size": {
            "stops": [
                [0, 0],
                [9, 0],
                [10, 10],
                [12, 12],
                [15, 30],
                [17, 35],
                [18, 40],
                [19, 50],
                [20, 60],
                [21, 70],
            ]
        }
    }
});

var all_layers= //a_list_of_all_my_layers_names;
var all_label_layers= //a_list_of_all_my_layers_names;

 for (var j = 0; j < all_layers.length; j++) {
    if ( current_layer === all_layers[j]) {
      map.setLayoutProperty(all_layers[j], 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else {
      map.setLayoutProperty(all_layers[j], 'visibility', 'none');
    }
    if ( current_label_layer === all_label_layers[j]) {
      map.setLayoutProperty(all_label_layers[j], 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else {
      map.setLayoutProperty(all_label_layers[j], 'visibility', 'none');
    }
  }

let hoveredStateId = null;

map.on('click', current_layer, (e) => {
new mapboxgl.Popup()
.setLngLat(e.lngLat)
.setHTML(e.features[0].properties.properties_count);
/*.addTo(map);
removing this comment will make a popup visisble on map*/

map.flyTo({
center: e.lngLat
});

// if we have highlighted features, change their highlight state to false
if (hoveredStateId) {
     map.setFeatureState(
    { source: 'json_source', id: hoveredStateId },
    { current: false }
    );
}

hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
map.setFeatureState(
    { source: 'json_source', id: hoveredStateId },
    { current: true }
);

const hex_id= e.features[0].properties.hex_OGR_FID.toString();

});
 
// Change the cursor to a pointer when
// the mouse is over the states layer.
map.on('mouseenter', current_layer, () => {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
 
// Change the cursor back to a pointer
// when it leaves the states layer.
map.on('mouseleave', current_layer, () => {
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
```

The map is part of an app developed in a no-code platform in which debugging Javascript is nearly impossible, however I can tell that the code above does not produce any syntax errors. Still I cannot get a polygon to be highlighted when clicked

Wherever there are comments data is assigned automatically through other processes within the app.
The json file containing the data source with the polygons has the following format:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "id": 71363,
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [...]},
        "properties": {
            "hex_OGR_FID": 71363,
            "properties_count": 1
        }
    },
    //more items    
]
```

}

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Is there something that I am missing? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you get your code into a Codepen or something where you *can* debug it, and remove everything that is not relevant to your core question about highlighting polygons. For instance, all the stuff about markers, and the symbol layer, and the hover-over behaviour.

Comment: Also what is `stops: [[...]]` ? That is not valid JavaScript.